# Google Earth Engine: How to import data from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have finished the data process in Google Colab and upload these results to Google Cloud Storage (GCS), and I want to import these files from GCS to Google Earth Engine (GEE) via the python API provided by GEE.
The files in GCS looks like this:
[image]

While the code in Colab makes sure that they are exist:
[image]

However, when I write the import code:

```
outputAssetID = 'users/cjj/modis_process' 
!earthengine upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {outputJsonFile}
```

The message I got is:

```
Running command using Cloud API.  Set --no-use_cloud_api to go back to using the API

Manifests for TfRecord ingestion must have exactly one tileset with exactly one source.
```

Am I using this API in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

As the suggestion first line indicated:

Running command using Cloud API.  Set --no-use_cloud_api to go back to using the API

And according to the hint the source code imply that '''--no-use_cloud_api''' is used for **Disables the new experimental EE Cloud API backend**(
https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/ee/cli/eecli.py)

Therefore, there are some differences between old and new version of this API.

```
!earthengine --no-use_cloud_api upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {outputJsonFile}
```

finally using this code works.