# Importing image into Google Colab as Earth Engine asset from Google cloud storage

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-cloud, tensorflow

When I run the following code in Google Colab, the image gets imported from Earth Engine assets folder into Google Colab such that I can visualize it:

```
import ee
imageROI = ee.Image('users/username/fileName')
```

However, instead of referring an asset from the Earth Engine, I want to reference an image from google cloud storage. Is there any method to do so?  An example that has **not been working**:

```
import ee
imageROI = ee.Image('gs://bucket/fileName')
```

I am looking for something on these lines so that I can reference an image directly from Google cloud storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access imagery from Cloud Storage directly, you have to upload them as assets first. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331925/154371) post show how you can do that from Colab:

```
!earthengine --no-use_cloud_api upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {outputJsonFile}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! Alternatively, would it be possible to access it from a Google drive location? I am asking this because I am involved in a collaborative project with 2-3 other stakeholders and I am not sure what would happen to my EE assets if my account gets deactivated.

Comment: Unfortunately not.